# Vaadin flow (v14.7) TreeGrid editing

Tags: vaadin-flow, vaadin-grid, vaadin14, treegrid

Is it possible to edit certain cells (column) in a TreeGrid, similar to what GridPro offers in terms of editing ?

I don't seem to be finding such feature.

Comment: I didn't try it but you could use an editor maybe like in the Grid https://vaadin.com/docs/latest/ds/components/grid/#inline-editing-java-only

Comment: That was an option I was thinking of but as of Vaadin v 14.7 I had some issues with getting out of the edit mode when done editing a cell as described here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69932500/vaadin-14-grid-in-non-buffered-mode-exit-editor
I was wondering if the TreeGrid has something similar of what GridPro offeres with regards to cell editing...

Comment: No there is no TreeGridPro

Comment: Checkout my answer on the other question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69932500/vaadin-14-grid-in-non-buffered-mode-exit-editor/70767686#70767686